# Wildcard subdirectory in nginx location block

Tags: nginx

I have the following working vhost configuration:

```
server {
listen       443 ssl http2;
server_name  example.com;
root  /home/sites/example.com/html; #main dir for main site domain
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
...

}
```

Then I want to have subsite with this structure **example.com/sub1**, but for the sack of being organized, I don't want the sub1 to be in */home/sites/example.com/html*. I'd rather it to be in */home/sites/example.com/subsites*. So I add this location block, and it works

```
location /sub1/ {
  root  /home/sites/example.com/subsites;
  ....
}
```

The problem here is that if I want to create another subsite, I have to copy this block and change a little bit. For example, for *sub2*, I will have to make a directory name *sub2* in */home/sites/example.com/subsites* then add a location block like this:

```
location /sub2/ {
   root  /home/sites/example.com/subsites;
    ....
}
```

and I can access it via *example.com/sub2*

I want to make a location with regex matching, so that everytime I make a directory in */home/sites/example.com/subsites* (dir3, dir4, dir5,... dirN) so that those newly created dirs will be accessible via *example.com/dir3*, *example.com/dir4*, *example.com/dir5*,...*example.com/dirN*
I've tried with this block, nginx restart fine, but I can't access the newly created dirs, and only get 404 error

```
location ~* "/dir([0-9]{1,4})/" {
root  /home/sites/example.com/subsites;
}
```

Comment: What is in your nginx log files?

Comment: Your regex only matches three or four digit suffixes: `dir100`, `dir1001` etc.

Comment: @AlexD It doesn't show anything related to the regex or error. The system is online but I can't access *example.com/dir3* if I make a directory dir3 inside */home/sites/example.com/subsites*

Comment: @RichardSmith my bad, I meaned `{1,4}`, just a typo. But It still doesn't work.

Comment: with `location ~* "/dir([0-9]{1,4})/" {
root  /home/sites/example.com/subsites;
}` when I create a directory name *dir3* and access via *example.com/dir3*, I get a 404 error

Comment: The URI `/dir3` is not processed by this location, as there is no trailing `/`. You need to be clear how you want `/dir3` and `/dir3/` to behave and what `index` directive needs to be in force for the subsites. For example, do they process `.php` files?

Comment: Yes they process `.php` files, and `index` directive as follow:
`index index.php index.html index.htm;` and  `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird problem, I guess. In my `.conf` file there are these blocks:

```
location ~* /\.well-known {
    allow all;
}

location ~* /\. {
    deny all;
}

location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|swf|ico|pdf|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    expires 60d;
    access_log off;
}
```

When I put this block after those block, and access *example.com/dir3* (after making a directory `dir3` in `/home/sites/example.com/subsites`, it show 404 page.

```
location ~* "/dir([0-9]{1,4})/" {
root  /home/sites/example.com/subsites;
}
```

The problem is solved by moving this block above those blocks. I don't know the reason behind, but the problem is solved, anyway.